# Correct pronunciation of figure

Tags: pronunciation

I’m American, from the Midwest in particular and I always pronunced the word figure as ˈfi-gər.  I rarely have gotten any comments on that, though I have gotten comments on a similarity to a Canadian accent, such as a relaxed about along with process with a long o, (but that’s for another time).  It wasn’t until recently that some friends of mine started commenting on the way I say it.  I haven’t done too much research, so is my pronunciation technically incorrect?

Comment: "I haven’t done too much research" -- **some** research is expected as a prerequisite to post a question here. Good Luck.

Comment: Please add the research you've obviously done (see your comments below) to the question now, linked and attributed as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two pronunciations: **fi-gyər** and, like you pronounce, **fi-gər**. One is not more correct than the other, although the first pronunciation is, according to M-W, the more common in the US.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figure):

> ˈfi-gyər  , British and often US ˈfi-gər

Personally, I say fi-gyər and I'm from New York.

Comment: It's not a British pronunciation unless there is a following vowel. There's no /r/ in standard southern British English (aka, RP).

Comment: Well, around here many people say an emphasized fi-gyər, but if I were to ask someone a question who didn’t know the answer, I would oftentimes be met with being told to fi-gər it out.  By the way, I live close to Chicago so this might be a part of the dialect.

Comment: @Araucaria Argue with Merriam-Webster.

Comment: @HeWhoShallNotBeNamed I don't need to argue it with an American dictionary, [I can just look it up in a British one!](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/figure). The pronunciation is given right at the bottom of the entry there: /ˈfɪɡə/. This comment is for readers who may be misinformed by that incorrect info.

Comment: @Araucaria Merriam-Webster should correct that. Is it perhaps a Northern pronunciation? I don’t think they just made that up; M-W is a reputable dictionary.

Comment: @HeWhoShallNotBeNamed I think the point they were trying to address was whether there's a yod there. They've just overlooked the /r/ ...  . *Bigger* and *figure* still rhyme in SSBE.

Comment: @HeWhoShallNotBeNamed I did a little more research and the pronunciation fi-gər is standard  in countries with rhotic accents such as Ireland, Scotland, and Canada.  A previous answer quoted a book saying that it's an 'uneducated pronunciation in America'.  Says who?  That seems like an overgeneralization directed at foreigners learning English.  I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing, because it's standard in other rhotic countries except USA.  Is this something standardized by Webster or something?  Or was it a dialect feature that caught on to a standard accent?

Comment: I'm Canadian, and I pronounce it like fig-*yer* (as in bow-*yer*) rather than fig-*ger* (as in big-*ger*). I'm used to hearing the longer pronunciation in most cases. Most notably, I've never heard any sports announcer use the shorter pronunciation when saying "figure skating." I've only overheard people in informal conversation say "I'm gonna figger it out." But in formal speech, it's the longer pronunciation regardless of context.

Comment: @Jason Bassford What province are you from, because wiktionary says it's standard on Canada.  If you live closer to America or in a bigger city, that may influence your pronunciation.  I once went to Victoria, and I heard people say it like fig-ger.  That's why I'm wondering if it's a provincial thing, and sadly there are no online Canadian English dictionaries.

Comment: @Polemarchos I'm from Ontario—but that probably means nothing, given its size. More specifically, I'm from Toronto, which is close to the US border. However, I'm skeptical of assigning generalities in this case. My comment was more anecdotal than anything.

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree, it’s just interesting because I’ve heard it from a few Canadian people, such as an old high school teacher who’s Canadian, and Jordan Peterson in an interview, so I guess that it just depends on what the area the person you’re talking to grew up in.

Comment: @Polemarchos Says countless examples from popular culture. In the US, when representing a rural bumpkin, writers often write things like "figger it out" or "I figger I'm goin' to" to indicate the rural dialect. Such dialects are stereotypically associated with rural bumpkins and therefore considered substandard. It's easy to find examples, here are a couple: https://www.michigan-sportsman.com/forum/threads/cant-figger-it-out.602053/  http://www.lumandabnersociety.org/CHRISTMAS_2011.html

Comment: @barbecue That obviously is not a fair representation to make because just because they are not university pronunciations, doesn’t necessarily equate being an uncultured bumpkin.  In A Short History of American Literature, it says that Figure has lost its fine old pronunciation (“figger”) for a spelling pronunciation “figyure.”  This seems to indicate that it was originally standard for Americans to pronounce it the way I do, so therefore, the ‘bumpkin’ pronunciation is rather a traditional pronunciation for Americans.

Comment: @barbecue also, the pronunciation of figger is more in common with the original Latin pronunciation.  So really, I don’t understand why many people hold the traditional pronunciations in contempt, when it was really their ones that changed.

Comment: @Polemarchos Nothing you say contradicts my point. Stereotypes are not required to be factually correct or reasonable. It's a fact that Southern and especially Appalachain English is commonly associated with rural regions and poor education. Whether that association is fair, reasonable, or accurate is irrelevant. It's how it is.

Comment: @Polemarchos you might want to read a bit about the dialects of southern Appalachia. It has its roots in the speech of Scottish and Irish immigrants, and as you pointed out, in many ways it may be closer to the original language than English spoken in other regions. Nevertheless, the fact remains that in the US, that dialect is PERCEIVED as being a sign of poor education, possibly because of the poverty and isolation of the Appalachian regions.
[Here's a link](http://www.wvculture.org/history/journal_wvh/wvh30-2.html)  you might find interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
discussion or debate
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
answer,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 3):

A pronunciation can't be "technically incorrect", because pronunciation is not a technical matter. A common analogy used in linguistics for what "correctness" means in the context of language is clothing: we can say that it's "incorrect" to wear jogging clothes to an interview for a white-collar job, but this is because of social conventions/considerations, not because of any technical requirements. The definition of "correct" pronunciation is as much a matter of opinion as the definition of "correct" fashion.

The pronunciation of *figure* that rhymes with *bigger* has been criticized, especially in the context of American English:

> In proper British speech, *figure* rhymes with *bigger,* but never so in educated American speech. "The British pronunciation is sometimes heard in AmE," says Burchfield (1996), "but is usually condemned as substandard."

(*[The Big Book of Beastly Mispronunciations](https://books.google.com/books?id=YtojrMr0Ft4C&pg=PA201),* 2nd edition, by Charles Harrington Elster, 2005; p. 201)

The pronunciation with a palatal glide /j/ (like the sound that the letter "y" makes at the start of the word "yes") corresponds somewhat more regularly to the spelling, but this doesn't really prove anything about which pronunciation is "correct".

There are examples of words spelled with "u" that have undeniably irregular pronunciations: nobody claims it is "incorrect" to pronounce the noun *minute* without a palatal glide after the /n/.

#### Some historical context

As I mentioned in the previous section, the pronunciation with /j/ has a more regular correspondence with the spelling, and this was given some weight in the past by certain "orthoepists" or writers that were interested in prescribing "correct" pronunciation.

John Walker (an Englishman) wrote the following about the pronunciation of this word in his *[Critical Pronouncing Dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/acriticalpronou00conggoog#page/n262)* of 1791:

> ☞ There is a delicate and a coarse pronunciation of this word and its compounds. The first is such a pronunciation as makes the *u* short and shut, as if written *figger :* the last preserves the sound of *u* open, as if *y* were prefixed *fig-yure.* That this is the true sound of open *u,* see Principles, No. 8.

I'm not sure how exactly to interpret the meaning of Walker's terms "delicate" and "coarse" (my guess would be that he means the pronunciation *figger* was preferred in polite society ), but note that he seems to have a certain amount of bias towards the pronunciation with /j/ because of its regularity, describing it as "preserving" the "true sound" of the letter U.

There seems to have been some variability in the development of the "U" sound that was taken into English from French when this vowel occurred in an unstressed syllable. Although the "regular" pronunciations used in modern English mainly continue forms with glides, there is evidence for /j/-less pronunciations in a number of other words.

One example is **creature**: the /j/-less pronunciation survives in the dialectal form *critter.* The OED entry for *creature* says "The realization of the second syllable varied in Middle English and early modern English according to whether this syllable showed secondary stress; pronunciations of the type /ˈkriːtʃə/ ultimately reflect pronunciations with secondary stress, while pronunciations of the type /ˈkriːtə/ ultimately reflect pronunciations without such secondary stress. Compare forms at nature n., pasture n., etc."

The book *[English Pronunciation in the Eighteenth Century: Thomas Spence's Grand Repository of the English Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=dfYBKFjf-2cC&pg=PA144),* by Joan C. Beal, has a more detailed description of the relevant sound changes. In chapter 5 ("The Phonology of Eighteenth-Century English: Evidence from Spence's *Grand Repository and Contemporary Pronouncing Dictionaries"), Beal says

> “In unstressed syllables, alongside the development [of the vowel sound represented by the letter U] to /juː/, there existed a variant pronunciation with /ɪ/ or /ə/. Particularly before final /r/, evidence for this becomes increasingly common in the homophone lists of late seventeenth-century orthoepists, such as Cooper (1687), who has, for example, *centaury, century; ordure, order; pastor, pasture;* and *picture, pick’t her* as homophones. In this context, the pronunciation with /ɪ/ or /ə/ is not stigmatized in the seventeenth century, but in other environments it is less common in the seventeenth century. Cooper gives *scrupelous* in his Latin text (1685) as ‘facilitas causa’, but in the English edition (1687) as ‘barbarous speaking’.  As we move into the eighteenth century, though, criticism of the pronunciation /ɪr/ or /ər/ becomes more widespread: according to Sheldon (1938:275). ‘Swift ... writes creeter to indicate vulgar pronunciation’ in his *Polite Conversations.*

Comment: I don’t see why it would be criticized.  I did some research and I saw that it appears to be standard in places with rhotic accents such as Ireland, Scotland, and Canada.  I’m wondering whether I missed something here because if it’s standard in all varieties of English, where would we have gotten the sound then.  I would also say I’m educate, even if I don’t speak ‘Standard American’.

Comment: Educated*, and other people around where I live are too.  That part about it being said in ‘educated American speech’ just seems to me like an overgeneralization about pronunciation directed at foreigners learning English

Comment: Why can’t a pronunciation be “technically incorrect?” On the contrary, a pronunciation can be very incorrect. I once heard someone pronounce “metamorphose” like “meta-morf-oh-see.”

Comment: @sumelic I don’t see why it would be criticized. I did some research and I saw that it appears to be standard in places with rhotic accents such as Ireland, Scotland, and Canada. I’m wondering whether I missed something here because if it’s standard in all varieties of English, where would we have gotten the sound then. I would also say I’m educated, even if I don’t speak ‘Standard American’.

Comment: @sumelic There were variant English pronunciations the unstressed -ure.  One was a traditional English sound er, then the other one developed from French into yure.  The first pronunciation developed as a rule originally, being dominant among certain orthoepists such as Cooper.  The latter, as you showed, eventually became common as a rule for many later, but the words you showed developed into coalesced yods for many dialects, which naturally creates the er sound.  Since figure doesn’t do that, the coalesced words and figure in this case fit the first rule, so that’s why it was polite to

Comment: @sumelic Walker

Comment: @sumelic So it seems that the more traditional dialects in American English keep the first rule of the unstressed ure, while others did not keep that rule.  Also, the first rule of keeping it as an er sound could be justified from the fact that it was the original Latin to have a yodless unstressed u sound.

Comment: @sumelic In Shakespeare's lusty punning in Love's labour's lost: With contemporary analogues by Herbert Alexander Ellis, it seems that it was pronounced figger in the 16th century, so that backs up the original rule that I mentioned about the unstressed -ure sound.

Comment: @HeWhoShallNotBeNamed  Imagine Metamorphose as a character in a Greek tragedy, and suddenly that pronunciation becomes correct.

Comment: @barbecue What’s your point?

Comment: @HeWhoShallNotBeNamed I thought my point was rather obvious, but to clarify, a single word could have two different pronunciations without one of them being "wrong." Context matters.

Comment: @barbecue True, but you will agree that some words do have correct pronunciations, yes?

Comment: @HeWhoShallNotBeNamed Channeling William James now... It depends on how you define "correct." If you mean correct according to some absolute authority, then no, I don't think you can say that. If by "correct" you mean "most commonly accepted as correct by the majority" then sure.

Comment: @barbecue If by “some absolute authority” you mean a dictionary, then yes, that is what I mean by “correct.” Dictionaries tell us how words are used both prescriptively and descriptively, and the best ones (like M-W) do it completely without bias.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84794/discussion-between-barbecue-and-he-who-shall-not-be-named).